# Self-Contained reveal.js file without relative reveal.js folder using Pandoc

Tags: javascript, html, pandoc, reveal.js

I am having trouble producing a self-contained reveal.js slideshow with Pandoc when the reveal.js folder is not relative to the markdown file.

A simple Markdown file, Tester.md:

```
# Title Slide

# Second Slide
More stuff happening here

# Some more stuff
Hello
```

The reveal.js folder is located at "c:/Users/Jared/Documents/reveal.js".

Running

```
pandoc -s -S -t revealjs Tester.md -o TesterReveal.html -V revealjs-url:c:/Users/Jared/Documents/reveal.js
```

creates an HTML file that links to the appropriate reveal.js folder and everything works just fine.

However, if I set `--self-contained` Pandoc returns an error.

```
pandoc -s -S -t revealjs Tester.md -o TesterReveal.html -V revealjs-url:c:/Users/Jared/Documents/reveal.js --self-contained

pandoc.exe: Failed to retrieve c:/Users/Jared/Documents/reveal.js/css/reveal.min.css
InvalidUrlException "c:/Users/Jared/Documents/reveal.js/css/reveal.min.css" "Invalid scheme"
```

Setting `--self-contained` works fine if the reveal.js folder is relative to Tester.md.

So I imagine the combination of `--self-contained` and `-V revealjs-url:c:/Users/Jared/Documents/reveal.js` is the culprit.

Any ideas how to keep the reveal.js folder in its own place and still have `--self-contained` work properly.  I feel that copying the reveal.js folder into every presentation I do is not a good practice.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for the necromancy, but I was experiencing similar problems. I solved it by finding out my pandoc user data directory:

```
pandoc --version
```

downloading [the latest reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/releases), unzipping it into the user data directory, and renaming it to reveal.js (without the trailing version string).
Now I can create self-contained slideshows from any working directory without passing url parameters. This works for other formats that need scripts and stylesheets as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not thrilled with this solution but it works.  For each presentation I create a symbolic link (using Windows) inside that folder to the reveal.js folder that sits elsewhere on my computer.

```
mklink /D reveal.js C:\Users\Jared\Documents\reveal.js
```

Gets the job done and makes pandoc happy.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem using `--self-contained` to embed a css file within html output. On a whim I tried using `\\` as the path delimiter instead of `/` and it worked! You might try:

```
pandoc -s -S -t revealjs Tester.md -o TesterReveal.html -V revealjs-url:c:\\Users\\Jared\\Documents\\reveal.js
```